# Discrete Harmonic Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let $\Omega$ be a Lipschitz domain, $\Gamma\subset\partial\Omega$ with Lebesgue measure $>0$. Let $u_\Gamma\in V^h|_\Gamma$ be the trace of a finite element function. 
Then the following holds:
$$ |\mathcal H(u_\Gamma)|_{H^1(\Omega)} = \min_{\substack{v\in H^1(\Omega)\cap V^h\\ v|_\Gamma = u_\Gamma}} |v|_{H^1(\Omega)}$$

where $\mathcal H(u_\Gamma)$ is the discrete harmonic continuiation of $u_\Gamma$.

How do I show this? I have done a proof for harmonic functions, but how do I show this for a discrete function? And what does the discrete harmonic function have to do with the solution of a partial differential equation? Is it just the discrete solution of the discretization of laplace's equation?

Comment: Okay so I tried using an approach similar to the continuous proof: Let $v\in H^1(\Omega)\cap V^h$ with $v|_\Gamma = u_\Gamma$ some arbitrary function. Then we have, denoting the stiffness matrix of the finite element discretization with $K$, that $|v|_{H^1(\Omega)} = \langle v,v\rangle_K$ (is this actually correct? I'm not quite sure about what the H1-norm is for a discrete function).

Comment: We get: \begin{align*}|v|_{H^1} & = \langle v,v\rangle_{K} \\  & = \langle v-\mathcal H(u_\Gamma) + \mathcal H(u_\Gamma), v -\mathcal H(u_\Gamma)+\mathcal H(u_\Gamma)\rangle_K \\ & = \langle v,v\rangle_K + 2\langle v-\mathcal Hu_\Gamma, v-\mathcal Hu_\Gamma\rangle_K + \langle \mathcal H(u_\Gamma),\mathcal H(u_\Gamma)\rangle_K \\ & \geq \langle \mathcal H(u_\Gamma), \mathcal H(u_\Gamma)\rangle_K \\ & = |\mathcal H(u_\Gamma)|\end{align*} and hence the H1-norm of $\mathcal H (u_\Gamma)$ is minimal.